# Why does my tutorial app crash?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner making Android apps. Try doing a tutorial and add a Relative layout and a Gridlayout and some Imageviews. But my app crashes.

MainActivity.java

```
package se.jakobia.connect3;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        public void dropIn(View view) {

    ImageView counter =(ImageView)view;

    counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);

    counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);

    counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(300);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

and activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="se.jakobia.connect3.MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"


        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:src="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:src="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:src="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:src="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:src="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:src="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:src="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:src="@drawable/red" />


    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I got an error message FATAL EXCEPTION: main. And fatal Exceptions main. I don't understand what the error messag means.

I think I haven't done that much, so I don't understand why it is not working.

Comment: here is the error log:02-09 09:22:40.526 741-741/se.jakobia.connect3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: se.jakobia.connect3, PID: 741
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.jakobia.connect3/se.jakobia.connect3.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0:

Comment: please show your stacktrace completely

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the view in onCreate() . Since according to Android lifecycle onStart() -> onCreate() execute..
So, basically the problem is you are accessing imageView to set animation but you haven't initialized.
So, your code should be something like this-

```
`import      android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View; 
 import android.widget.ImageView; 
 public class MainActivity extends    AppCompatActivity 
 { 
 private ImageView counter;
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle   savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
counter = (ImageView) findViewById  (R.id.imageView);
counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);     counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);     counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(300); 
  }
}`
```

Comment: Try to remove transition and then execute.. code should run

Answer (score 0):

Please add this gradle file

`compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

and make the class below

```
public class MultiDexApplication extends Application {
    public MultiDexApplication() {
    }

    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

and define in manifest also